# Splitting tuple item in a list

Tags: python, python-2.7, split, tuples

How do I split the 2nd tuple

```
data = [('152', 'Farko', 'Kier'), ('153', 'Park - Pub')]
```

to get this output:

```
[('152', 'Farko', 'Kier'), ('153', 'Park',  'Pub')]
```

I tried this way:

```
lst = []
for i in data:
    if len(i) == 2:
        i[1] = tuple(i[1].split(' - '))
    lst.append(i)
```

It'd work, except it raised an exception `TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment`. But I can't assign `i = tuple(i[1].split(' - '))` because I need to keep the number which is in position `i[0]` in tuple. List comprehansion solution would be greatly welcome. Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension:

```
lst = [t[:1] + tuple(t[1].split(' - ')) if len(t) == 2 else t for t in data]
```

or you could adjust your loop to create a new tuple:

```
for i in data:
    if len(i) == 2:
        i = i[:1] + tuple(i[1].split(' - '))
    lst.append(i)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
newdata = [tuple(s for t in tu for s in t.split(' - ')) for tu in data]
# [('152', 'Farko', 'Kier'), ('153', 'Park', 'Pub')]
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have seen you can't modify the tuple, however you can just create a new one with the data you want:

```
data = [('152', 'Farko', 'Kier'), ('153', 'Park - Pub')]
lst = []
for i in data:
    if len(i) == 2:
        i = i[:1] + tuple(i[1].split(' - '))
    lst.append(i)
```

Or if you want to modify the original list:

```
for i, tup in enumerate(data):
    if len(tup) == 2:
        data[i] = tup[:1] + tuple(tup[1].split(' - '))
```